# When is an ideal also a ring, and could then be anything said about its relation to the original ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, ideals

If $R$ is a ring with unity $1$, then $S \subseteq R$ is called a *subring* if it is itself a ring with $1 \in S$. A subset $I \subseteq R$ is called an *ideal* if it is a group with respect to addition and $rx, xs \in I$ for each $r,s \in $ and $x \in I$. With these definitions an ideal $I$ is a subring iff $1 \in I$ iff $I = R$, hence there are no proper ideals that are also subrings of $R$.

If we change the definition and look at rings without requiring an identity, then every ideal is also a subring, but not every subring needs to be an ideal. This could be read [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subring#Relation_to_ideals). There it is also stated that not every ideal has itself an identity, examples as given there are $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$, other are in quotient polynomial rings, where ideals have identites, see for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1639202/two-ways-to-decompose-mathbb-qg-for-g-1-g-g2-and-their-interrelati).

But lets look at rings with unity from now on. If an ideal has unity, then it is itself a ring with unity, but the identity might be different, and I ask myself it what sense is the ring structure on the ideal then different from the ring structure on the given ring.

> What are the conditions that ensure that ideals have identites, and hence form rings by themself? And what is the relation to the original ring? Could we give a ring homomorphism from the ring to the ideal then?

I give a special case, which came up on a recent question of mine (see the linked one above), and is in some way related to representation theory, where similar constructions are used.

Let $R$ be a ring with unity, then $R$ could be regarded as $R$-module by its regular action on itself, and the $R$-submodules are precisely the ideals then. Now suppose (considered as a module) we have $R = I \oplus J$ for two $R$-submodules. In the module we have $R / I \cong J$ as modules, i.e. we have a module isomorphism. Now if we look at $R$ as a ring again, then $I$ and $J$ are ideals, and so we can built the quotient ring $R / I$. Now I want to look at the relation of this quotient ring to $J$ (or $R / I$ as a module), and want to know if they are isomorphis as rings. In this special case if we write $1 = 1_I + 1_J$, then $1_J$ is an identity in $J$, as for $x \in J$ we have $x = x1 = x(1_I + 1_J) = x1_I + x1_J$ and $x1_I \in I$ and $x1_I \in J$ by the ideal properties, hence $x = x1_J$. So $J$ has a unity and is a ring. The map $\pi : R \to J$ gives a surjective homomorphism (it is like a projection) and its kernel is precisely $I$, hence $R / I \cong J$. But this situation is very special.

But in general, when are ideals also rings with unity, and what is their relation to the original ring?

Comment: Subrings don't necciserly have the unit in them.

Comment: I understood the definition given on wikipedia that way, and I think it is pretty clear that they mean the same unity in the substructure. Also as written in S. Lang *Algebra* he defines subring: "A subset $B$ of a ring $A$ is called a **subring** if it is an additive subgroup, if it contains the multiplicative unit, and if $x,y \in B$ implies $xy \in B$". Maybe there are other definitions around.

Comment: @Stefan yes, there are, and the description you provided for "subring" is a little ambiguous. In the very first description  It would be best to emphasize that the $1$ in both rings is the same element (since $1$ can be interpreted as generic notation for the identity of whatever ring is currently being talked about.) this makes the distinction from your later line of thought clear.

Comment: I added $1 \in S$. So now it should be clear. But anyway, the particular definition of a subring is not that important for my question. As I am asking when ideals are rings with a possible different multiplication and possible different identity.

Comment: I think you should say "Unital subring" for that because in many instances subring doesn't need it, rings in general do not need a unit. $2\mathbb{Z}$ is a ring but it has no unit for example.

Comment: @ZelosMalum Different people have different definitions, it's not rare to require a multiplicative identity. Things like $2\mathbb{Z}$ are then usually called "rngs" (without 'i').

Comment: how would you even pronounce that?

Comment: Proves how sensitive these notions are to context and definition. But as said my first two paragraphs are just meant as a motivation and do not relate that much to the actual question, which is concerned with ideals. Maybe I should consider deleting the part about subrings...

Comment: @ZelosMalum I think most people say "rng" as "rung," but my teacher joked it was pronounced "wrong." You might also find it amusing to know that semirings (rings where the underlying abelian group is relaxed to a commutative monoid, so there are 'no negatives') are sometimes called "rigs" (no n). Much easier to pronounce...

Comment: I'll go with "wrong" because it's just wrong on all fronts

Comment: @ZelosMalum You don't believe in rings without identity? or just in the name "rng"?

Comment: I say that rings do not need identity to be rings, only unital rings require a unit/identity :)

Comment: @ZelosMalum fair enough!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> when are ideals also rings with unity?

**Proposition:** An ideal $I\lhd R$ will be a ring with identity iff there exists a central idempotent $e$ such that $eR=I$.

*Proof:*

($\implies$) The identity of $I$, call it $e$, is an idempotent element of $R$ and satisfies $I=eI$. Then $I=eI\subseteq eR\subseteq I$, so $I=eR$.

Since $e\in I$, we have $(1-e)Re\subseteq I=eR$. But $(1-e)Re\subseteq (1-e)R$ too, so $(1-e)Re\subseteq (1-e)R\cap eR=\{0\}$.

On the other hand, $e$ acting as a right identity on $I$ is equivalent to the condition that $I(1-e)=\{0\}$. Or in other symbols $eR(1-e)=\{0\}$.

These last two conditions imply that $e$ is central: $er-re=ere-re=-(1-e)re=0$.

---

> what is their relation to the original ring?

You have the isomorphism of rings $R\cong eRe\oplus (1-e)R(1-e)$ given by the obvious mapping. (Things are simplified a bit since the $e$'s on the right can commute so that $ere=er$ and $(1-e)r(1-e)=(1-e)r$.) Replacing $eRe=eR=I$, you can see $\frac{R}{(1-e)R(1-e)}\cong I$ as rings.

For any idempotent $e\in R$, the set $eRe$ forms a ring called the "corner ring of $e$." A corner ring gets its name from the following isomorphism:

$$
R\cong \begin{bmatrix}eRe&eR(1-e)\\ (1-e)Re&(1-e)R(1-e)\end{bmatrix}
$$

$(1-e)$ is also an idempotent, and $(1-e)R(1-e)$ is its corner ring.

When the off-diagonal entries are zero, you can see how the ring splits into two pieces as described above. The pieces can behave independently, though. If $eR$ is an ideal, then the $2,1$ position is zero, but the $1,2$ position need not be zero. In our case, it turns out that $eR$ having a right identity implies that the $1,2$ position is also zero. But in principal, that position could be nonzero.

Comment: Why do we have $(1-e)Re \subseteq eR \cap (1-e)R = 0$; that $(1-e)Re \subseteq (1-e)R$ is clear, but why $(1-e)Re \subseteq eR$? Also is the requirement $eR(1-e) = 0$ essential?

Comment: @Stefan $e$ is in the ideal $eR$, so it absorbs (1-e)R$ into $eR$ as well. Without $eR(1-e)=0$, $e$ would not be a right identity

Comment: Sorry, I do not see that $e \in eR$ implies $(1-e)R \subseteq eR$?

Comment: @Stefan good, because that is a false statement that nobody claimed to be true. The conclusion is that $(1-e)Re\subseteq eR$

Comment: Is it $eR = (1-e)Re + eRe = (1-e)Re + eR$, hence $(1-e)Re \le eR$?

Comment: @Stefan if $I$ is an ideal, and x\in I$ and S is any nonempty subset of $R$, then $Sx\subseteq I$. Apply this to $I=eR$ and $S=(1-e)R$

Comment: Okay, just one last question: $eR$ is not a two-sided ideal in general, just in this case?

Comment: @Stefan Oops, didn't realize I borked a dollar sign somewhere in my last comment. Fixing it here:  "if $I$ is an ideal, and $x\in I$ and $S$ is any nonempty subset of and $R$ , then $Sx\subseteq I$ . Apply this to $I=eR$ and $S=(1-e)R$"

Comment: @Stefan : Yes, that is correct, $eR$ is not necessarily an ideal. Here, we have it as an assumption. If $I$ is a two-sided ideal with an identity $e$, then $I=eI\subseteq eR\subseteq I$, so $I=eR$. Similarly $I=Re$. Both $Re$ and $eR$ are the ideal $I$ under these assumptions.

Comment: @Stefan I went ahead and incorporated some of our discussion into the answer since I am at a real computer now (and not on a mobile device.)